# burg returns to default after running "sudo update-burg"

Tags: grub2, 14.04, bootloader, customization, burg

I made 2 custom icons for the burg bootloader-1.A custom icon for Bodhi linux and 2.Gnome linux....I placed these images in the correct folders and changed their classes appropriately....I then start up burg manager and click Burg EMU and can see my images are in fact there.However after running "sudo update-burg" my icons disappear and everything returns back to default....Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I have tried editing the etc/burg.d as well as grub2.How can I edit Burg and the changes stick.

I am using the magic theme [image] and I ve posted one of the custom images I made for this theme......My custom icons are in the correct folder.....I have edited the burg.cfg file-menuentry "gnome" --class gnome --class os --group group_/dev/sda3 {
    insmod ext2......I have edited it to be class gnome from class ubuntu....When it stays as class gnome my icon stays but as soon as I update burg it changes back to class ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you're really sure that you place the icons in the right place, I'll still consider that you might have been wrong :

- Images should be PNG 32bit
- Images need to go in /boot/burg/themes/nameoftheme/folderwrittenintheme/nameofimage.png
- You need to select the theme when you are in the real Burg, with F2
- You might need proper rights for the images, check with `ls -l`

Once your images are in the right folder, that the theme works (it appears to be working with burg-emu, so it should be good), run `sudo update-burg`

Reboot your computer and select the theme with F2 on Burg. You might want to select another theme than switch again to the right one.

Don't forget that, as grub, Burg could be installed on multiples partitions, so make sure that when you update Burg, it's updated for the partition that boots.

You image works perfectly for me : see the crappy picture I just took
[image]

---

You set a new class "gnome", from "ubuntu". But when you run `sudo update-burg`, the burg.cfg file is changed. You need to re-edit it manually, or specify your change in *burg.d* configurations files.

Comment: The custom icons do show up when I check burg emu so I would think they are in their proper place however upon "sudo update-burg" burg goes back to default icons.

Comment: I understood perfectly.

Comment: .I have edited the burg.cfg file-menuentry "gnome" --class gnome --class os --group group_/dev/sda3 { insmod ext2......I have edited it to be class gnome from class ubuntu....When it stays as class gnome my icon stays but as soon as I update burg it changes back to class ubuntu

Comment: I think I know... Check my answer, I edit it